# SparkContext has been shutdown while creating pipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark, xgboost

Working on a pipeline for the model training. I use both numerical and categorical features. It works fine separately until I try to combine different types of features.

```
private def pipeline: Pipeline = {
  val cat_features = getFeaturesByType(this.taskConfig, "categorical")
  val num_features = getFeaturesByType(this.taskConfig, "numeric")
  val catIndexer = cat_features.map {
    feature => new StringIndexer().setInputCol(feature).setOutputCol(feature + "_index")
  }
  val cat_features_index = cat_features.map {
    (feature: String) => feature + "_index"
  }
  this.modelFeatures = cat_features_index ++ num_features
  val catFeatureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(cat_features_index)
    .setOutputCol("cat_features")
  val numFeatureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(num_features)
    .setOutputCol("num_features")
  val featureAssembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("cat_features", "num_features"))
    .setOutputCol("features")
  val pipelineStages = catIndexer ++
    Array(catFeatureAssembler, numFeatureAssembler, featureAssembler)
  TaskLogger.INFO(pipelineStages.toList.toString())
  new Pipeline().setStages(pipelineStages)
}
private def estimator(paramMap: Map[String, Any]): XGBoostEstimator = {
  new XGBoostEstimator(paramMap)
    .setFeaturesCol("features")
    .setLabelCol("indexed_label")
}
```

The app goes down on calling

```
val preprocessed = this.pipelineModelTransform(dataset)
this.estimatorModel = Some(xgbEstimator.fit(preprocessed))
```

> SparkContext has been shutdown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: SparkContext has been shutdown

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2021)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1354)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1327)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1368)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1367)

    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.ml$dmlc$xgboost4j$scala$spark$XGBoost$$postTrackerReturnProcessing(XGBoost.scala:393)

    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$4.apply(XGBoost.scala:356)

    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$4.apply(XGBoost.scala:337)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)

    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)

    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)

    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainDistributed(XGBoost.scala:336)

    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:139)

    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostEstimator.train(XGBoostEstimator.scala:36)

    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)

    at jp.co.yahoo.k2.i2i.optimizer.model.XGBoostRanker.fit(XGBoostRanker.scala:67)

    at jp.co.yahoo.k2.i2i.optimizer.Optimizer$.train(Optimizer.scala:151)

    at jp.co.yahoo.k2.i2i.optimizer.Optimizer$.main(Optimizer.scala:78)

    at jp.co.yahoo.k2.i2i.optimizer.Optimizer.main(Optimizer.scala)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)

    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I use xgboost4j spark 0.72 and spark 2.20

Comment: you havn't mentioned anything about sparkcontext issue, you may want to add more details

Comment: @sumitya added the error traceback. Please have a look.